# Arithmetic comparison in a shell

Tags: shell

i want to compare two number values in a shell script (sh) but it doesn`t work:

```
#!/bin/sh
let a=30
let b=100
let x=$a-$b
echo $a $b $x
[ $a < $b ] && { echo ok; }
```

That outputs:

```
30 100 -70
./x: line 6: 100: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that should be -lt (which stands for less than) rather than "<".  "<" is for string comparisons.

Edit: Actually looking at this now it seems clear what the problem is.  The "<" character does file redirection so that's what the shell is trying to do.  You can escape that character by doing \< instead but as originally stated that will do string comparison rather than numeric comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Replace < with -lt

Also, lose the "let." This isn't Basic. Bill Gates and Steve Ballmer (Developers!) have nothing to do with this universe.

Answer (score 0):

"let" is perfectly fine in shell, and has nothing to do with M$ basic or what.!
@OP , you can use bc to compare numbers, especially if you are also comparing floats. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786888/in-bash-shell-script-how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-number/1787060#1787060) for similar example

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/sh
let a=30
let b=100
let x=$a-$b
echo $a $b $x
if(($a < $b)) then 
  echo ok
fi
```